# Square flex item within container with dynamic height/width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to build an image list, where images can have different sizes, as well as the container.

The images work according to my wishes, but the last element, the input wrapper, doesn't.

I would like to have the last item (the input file wrapper) to use the full height of the container, and be shaped as a square.

I tried multiple styles but I am unable to stop the following problems:

- When there is a lot of space left in the container, the last item becomes too wide
- When the container is full, the last item become too narrow

```css
.container {
        resize: both;
        width:1000px;
        height:200px;
        border:1px solid #000;

        display:flex;
        overflow-x:auto;
        overflow-y:hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        align-items:flex-start;
        padding:0.25rem 0;
      }

      .container>* {
        border:1px solid #000;

        max-width:200px;
        max-height:100%;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
      }

      .container>*:not(:first-child) {
        margin-left:1rem;
      }

      .inputfilewrapper {
        display: inline-block;
        flex:1 0 0px;
        height:100%;
      }

      .inputfile {
        display: none;
      }

      .inputfile + label {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
      }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
  <div class="inputfilewrapper">
    <input type="file" id="random123" class="inputfile">
    <label for="random123">[+]</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

The desired result is shown in red in the following picture above the actual version:
[image: Desired result 1]
[image: Desired result 2]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you be a bit more clear? Maybe add images of the problem and what you want.

Comment: I would like to have the last item (the input file wrapper) to use the full height of the container, and be shaped as a square

Comment: do u want to make all the boxes inside the container of equal size

Comment: only the last box should be square, the other ones work as expected in the snippet